# Cloud Endpoints Authentication

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using App Engine Standard with the Python 2 runtime and Endpoints Frameworks.
When making a request, the app just returns "Successful" if the request was completed.  I am trying to implement authentication so unauthenticated users are not able to complete the request. I've done the following:

1. Modified my main.py decorator to include issuers and audience:

```
issuers={'serviceAccount': endpoints.Issuer('[MYSERVICEACCOUNT]', 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/[MYSERVICEACCOUNT]')}, 
audiences={'serviceAccount': ['[MYSERVICENAME]-dot-[MYPROJECT].appspot.com']}
```

2. Modifed my main.py method to check for a valid user:

```
user = endpoints.get_current_user()
if user is None:
   raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('You must authenticate first.')
```

3. Regenerated and redeployed my openAPI document. It now has security and securityDefinitions sections.
4. Updated my app.yaml to reference that Endpoints version.
5. Redeployed my app

To make an authorized request to my app, I have done the following:

1. I gave the service account the Service Consumer role on my Endpoints service.
2. Generate a signed jwt using the generate_jwt function from Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication). I am passing in credentials using the service account's json key file.

```
    payload = json.dumps({
        "iat": now,
        "exp": now + 3600,
        "iss": [MYSERVICEACCOUNT],
        "sub": [MYSERVICEACCOUNT],
        "aud": [MYSERVICENAME]-dot-[MYPROJECT].appspot.com
    })
```

3. Make the request using make_jwt_request function from Google's documentation.

```
   headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt),
        'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

I am getting 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: After you call .get_current_user(), do you verify that user is not None?

Comment: @RoseDavidson I had not. I've added that in and editted my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a support ticket with Google, it turns out Google's documentation was incorrect. The main.py function needs to check for an authenticated user in the below manner:

```
providers=[{ 
'issuer': '[YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT]', 
'cert_uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/raw/[YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT]', 
}] 

audiences = ['[YOUR-SERVICE-NAME]-dot-[YOUR-PROJECT-NAME].appspot.com'] 

user = endpoints.get_verified_jwt(providers, audiences, request=request) 
if not user: 
  raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException
```

After making that change, I got the following error when trying to make an authenticated request:

> Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: AttributeError ('unicode' object has no attribute 'get')

This was caused by how I was generating the payload with json.dumps().  I generated without json.dumps() like below:

```
payload = {
  "iat": now,
  "exp": now + 3600,
  "iss": [MYSERVICEACCOUNT],
  "sub": [MYSERVICEACCOUNT],
  "aud": [MYSERVICENAME]-dot-[MYPROJECT].appspot.com
}
```

These two changes fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your audiences don't match; in your code, you are requiring an audience of `[MYSERVICEACCOUNT]`, but when generating the JWT, your audience is `[MYSERVICENAME]-dot-[MYPROJECT].appspot.com`. These need to match.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed the audience in my main.py to be the hostname. I editted my post with the change. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There are few details, which might be worth checking:

- The list of allowed audiences should contain the value of `aud` claim of a client-generated JWT token. This is what Rose has pointed out.
- All of the JWT claims presented in sample client [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#python) are present. Your code is missing the `email` claim in the JWT `payload` dictionary.
- The method you're accessing requires no specific OAuth scopes. The scopes are set as the `scopes` field of `@endpoints.method` decorator.

Comment: I had to use the endpoints.get_verified_jwt() function to validate the user. That resolved my issue.